# Algorithmic Complexity of NLTK Tokenizer

Tags: python, big-o

```
    for line in file:
        token = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w')
        listtoken = token.tokenize(line)
```

For this code, what would the Big-O Notation of this code in terms of time? Would it be considered linear time? I know that token.tokenize creates a list of tokens for each line in the file. So, if you are iterating through each line in the file and calling .tokenize, would that be a very bad time complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is definitely not linear as you are calling a function (RegexpTokenizer) that might take at the least linear time, n times where n is the number of lines in the file.

So if we assume RegexpTokenizer is O(m) where m is the size of the line, the complexity of the entire code is O(m*n).

But this sentence need not be true as to understand the running timer further, we need to look at the [internal working of the tokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html)

So the broad assumption could be O(n*m) but the actual complexity can be greater than that.

> So, if you are iterating through each line in the file and calling
>   .tokenize, would that be a very bad time complexity?

Even the complexity seems to be bad, I think this is necessary if you have to tokenize each sentence.

Comment: If  I'm measuring time complexity where m is instead the number of chars in the input, would it be the same thing where RegexpTokenizer is O(m) and the overall time complexity is O(m*n) and n is the number of lines in the file? Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: @smith1453 By size of the line, I meant number of characters in the input, so yes